# python spyder interactive python console hangs on matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)|

spyder 2.3.6

matplotlib 1.4.3

```
>>> fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
```

will generate a figure window. It doesn't matter whether I close that figure window or not, spyder console hangs on new commands, unless I press ctrl-C

```
>>> 1+1


2 (this 2 does not show until I press ctrl-C)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-    packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 297, in     qt_nt_inputhook
QtCore.QCoreApplication.exec_()
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

However, if I put everything in a script and run with "interactive after execution", it will go through to the end, give me >>> prompt, but hang on new commands